# ffmpeg with m3u8: video and audio not synchronized

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, synchronization, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I noticed while using **ffmpeg** to download m3u8 streaming playlist, I get sometimes faster video. 
If the content of the url **master.m3u8** is the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=620941,RESOLUTION=640x352,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2"
https://hello/world.m3u8
```

If I'm not mistaken, **ffmpeg** should be able to decode the **EXT-X-STREAM-INF** information and assign the default value while downloading.
But when I run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://hello/darkness/my/old/friend/master.m3u8" -c copy "Some Video File.ts"
```

I get a video that is faster than the Audio.
If I run this command without the **-c copy**:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://hello/darkness/my/old/friend/master.m3u8" "Some Video File.ts"
```

I get a video and audio synchronized. But the video quality is worse.

What's the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't need to transcode the video. Switch `-c copy` to `-c:v copy -c:a aac`. As for the original issue, have to see the console output.

Comment: @Mulvya `mpegtsenc` has a problem when stream copying. In some cases the container timebase is not correctly calculated and the muxer uses this information to calculate PCR rates which are way off the 100ms limit imposed by the standard. There's a `TODO` in the code and the fix might be as simple as using the average framerate instead but one needs to check if it doesn't impact other things.

Comment: Pinging @LordNeckbeard https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mpegtsenc.c#L977